# Find the index of a number in the fibonacci sequence

Tags: bash, shell, recursion

I want to find the **index** of a number in the fibonacci sequence using **recursion**.

**Example** : 13 (my input) is the 8th (output) number of the fibonacci sequence

Here is my function :

```
#!/bin/bash

function fib() {
    
number=1
cpt=1   
if [[ $number -lt $1 ]]
then
    compteur=$(($cpt+ 1))
    echo $(( $(fib $(($number - 1)) ) + $(fib $(($number - 2)) ) ))
fi
echo $cpt
}

fib $1
```

I have this error : Wrong symbol near the +

Then I don't know if my logic for the algorithm is good. I don't know if my syntax of how we are calling the function in the recursion in bash is great.

Any help would be appreciated. *Thanks* !

Comment: Just wondering, what is the expected output/index for the input/fibonacci number `1`? The number `1` appears twice in the fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Right, didn't expected that ^^ I might do a statement that returns 2 and 3 in my opinion

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The code outputs `2 1` for any input.

Comment: @HugoSab What do you expect if the input is not a member of the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: Il already have a script that returns me if the number is in the Fibonacci sequence. At the end I want that my script print :
The number is in the fibonacci sequence at the index [ ...]

Comment: Is use of recursion required?

Comment: Yes, I need to step up on this type of algorithms. And in my exercise, this is mentionned that I have to use recursion :/

Comment: It is well known that it is extremely inefficient to apply recursion to generate Fibonacci sequence because the number of recursion increases exponentially. You should keep that in your mind especially if you are learning algorithms. If your teacher directs you to use recursion, better to blame him/her.

Comment: @tshiono, although I agree with your point, the teacher probably wants them to demonstrate recursion, not algorithmics.  @HugoSag: What use is `compteur` ?  In bash, I tend to avoid nesting to much stuff like you did here.  I would get fib(-1) in a variable, fib(-2) in another, then add those.  This way you know which one caused issues, if ever.  Other detail, you did not tell up wich `+` is causing the issue (although it is probably the `$(( $(( )) + $(( )) ))` line...

Answer (score 0):

With `recursion`, would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# "fib n" returns the nth Fibonacci number (n starts from 0)
fib() {
    local n=$1
    if (( n == 0 )); then
        echo "0"
    elif (( n == 1 )); then
        echo "1"
    else
        echo "$(( $(fib "$(( n - 1 ))" ) + $(fib "$(( n - 2 ))" ) ))"
    fi
}

input=$1                        # user's input as a 1st argument to this script

for (( i = 0; ; i++ )); do      # increment the index i starting from 0
    f=$(fib i)
    (( f >= input)) && break    # if "fib i" >= input, then exit the loop
done

if (( f == input )); then       # the input is a Fibonacci number
    echo "$i"
else
    echo "$i (input $input is not a Fibonacci number.)"
fi
```

By convention, the index starts with "0", then 13 is the 7th Fibonacci number.
Btw if you increase the input number, you'll see the execution of the script takes a while (e.g. please try with 987 as an input).
Here is an alternative without the recursion:

```
#!/bin/bash

f0=0
f1=1

input=$1

for (( i = 0; ; i++ )); do
    (( f0 >= input )) && break
    f2=$(( f1 + f0 ))
    f0=$f1
    f1=$f2
done

if (( f0 == input )); then
    echo "$i"
else
    echo "$i (input $input is not a Fibonacci number.)"
fi
```

Although the `recursion` is mathematically simple and elegant, the number
of computation depends on the implementation. Fibonacci sequence is a
typical example which requires a consideration.
The 1st script includes two problems:

- In the 1st recursion, the `fib` function calls two `fib` functions.
  In the 2nd recursion, four functions are called. The number of computation
  reaches O(2**N).
- The intermediate values such as fib(n-1) and fib(n-2) are discarded and
  calculated again in the next invocation.